# Getting error In posting Data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am sending the data using post method like this

```
let login = ["user_name":usernameTextField.text,"password":passwordTextField.text]
    //["user":"ords_user@gmail.com", "pass":"ords_password"]

let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8300")!

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

do {
    // JSON all the things
    let auth = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(login, options: .PrettyPrinted)

    // Set the request content type to JSON
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    // The magic...set the HTTP request method to POST
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // Add the JSON serialized login data to the body
    request.HTTPBody = auth

    // Create the task that will send our login request (asynchronously)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        // Do something with the HTTP response
        print("Got response \(response) with error \(error)")
        print("Done.")
    })

    // Start the task on a background thread
    task.resume()

} catch {
    // Handle your errors folks...
    print("Error")
}
```

But I am getting the error message like

> Argument type '[String : String?]' does not conform to expected type ‘AnyObject’

If I give the direct string it is accepting. If I am giving dynamically using the TextFields it is not coming. I don’t know what is the mistake I have done.

Can anyone Please help to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line are you getting the actual error?

Comment: let auth = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(login, options: .PrettyPrinted) at "login"

Comment: Unwarp your textField's text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are putting optional strings into the dictionary.

Try doing this:

```
guard 
    let username = usernameTextField.text, 
    let password = passwordTextField.text else { 
        return print("Need username & password") 
}
let login = ["user_name": username,"password": password]
...
```

Comment: @anushahrithi just updated my answer, it should have been `let login = ["user_name": username,"password": password]`

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField`'s text property returns an optional value, so compiler can't convert it to AnyObject. 
You have to unwrap optionals before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let login = ["user_name":usernameTextField.text,"password":passwordTextField.text] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Comment: That won't compile textfields text return an optional.

Comment: But here problem is not of optional value.

Comment: You want to throw that into a Playground and tell me if its not a problem?